# html absolute and relative offset from each other

Tags: html, css

I'm having and issue using an html document with style controlled by an externally linked css.  I'm rendering locally and have tried both chrome and firefox.

This issue is this:

I have two `<div>` elements both with height and width values of 200px (I'm placing colored squares onto the webpage).  However their position attribute values differ.  One's "absolute" the other's "relative".  I'm essentially trying to lay the two boxes on top of each other.  For example (in the css file)

```
#item1{position: absolute; left:300px; top: 300px; z-index: 1;}

#item2{position: relative; left:300px; top: 300px; z-index: 2;}
```

item2 will be offset from item1 by 8 pixels, down and to the right.

I've tried setting all margins (and padding) to zero on item2 but didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: `absolute` and `relative` do different things, and it's not clear why you're using one versus the other here, nor exactly what you're trying to achieve. Also, you should include your HTML - preferably as a snippet (see the button on the toolbar)

Comment: (but you might want to try setting margins and padding to zero on your `body`)

Comment: @Uday that's not correct - for a `relative` element, `top` and `left` are relative to the element's own normal position, which is different to how it works for `absolute`, but they do work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get to [LearnLayout.com/position.html](http://learnlayout.com/position.html) right away to understand and solve this. Then read through the entire site (it won't take long and you'll thank me) -- it's the best site I've ever seen on everything that frustrates people about css. It will save you hours and days in the long run.

Comment: Yes, I thank you.  The solution I needed (and much more) was on the site.  I solved the issue by creating a style for body {margin; 0;}.  It lined things up.  Thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome @painter. Rather perplexed that the answer is marked as correct but has a negative score.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: absolute;` for both divs.

Try changing item2 to:

```
#item2{position: absolute; left:308px; top: 308px; z-index: 2;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  your solution did work to align the elements how I wanted.  However I wan't satisfied since the original behavior (i.e. keeping left:300px) wasn't performing as expected.  This was a learning exercise for me.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Can you accept it as the answer please? :)

Comment: Actually, the previous answer pointing me to LearnLayout.com/position turned out to be exactly what I was looking for ( a solution to the larger issue of why the two dive elements with positions of 300 where offset from each other).  I'm sorry since this was one of my first (if not the very first) question I've posted here on stackoverflow and didn't accept that the previous answer as I wasn't exactly sure how that worked.  Thank you very much for your time and your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Both divs must be positioned absolute if you want to place one div on top of the other.

Comment: Unfortunately the parameters of the problem I'm working on require one div to be absolute and the other relative.  Thanks!